# Where is my Microsoft.Windows.Themes assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I wrote a user control in XAML and after it gets compiled into C# the resulting C# has this line:

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Themes;
```

Which throws an error now:

> The type or namespace name 'Themes' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I figured since I can't affect the output of compiled C# (there's nothing to remove from XAML), I would just add that as Reference.

However, the Add Reference dialog does not contain `Microsoft.Windows.Themes`. Is this not part of .NET?

Here's an example XAML user control that causes this problem:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GG.UserControls.MainMenu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <StackPanel>
        <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}">
            ... // Just static menu items.
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

And C# code behind it:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GG.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainMenu.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainMenu : UserControl
    {
        public MainMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of compiled C#:

```
#pragma checksum "..\..\..\..\UserControls\MainMenu.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "5A85C5B16565514165AD23641F944BC6"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17020
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using GG;
using GG.UserControls;
using Microsoft.Windows.Shell;
using Microsoft.Windows.Themes; // <---- WTF?
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;


namespace GG.UserControls {


    /// <summary>
    /// ChangesetHistory
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainMenu : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {

        private bool _contentLoaded;

        /// <summary>
        /// InitializeComponent
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        public void InitializeComponent() {
            if (_contentLoaded) {
                return;
            }
            _contentLoaded = true;
            System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/GG;component/usercontrols/mainmenu.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

            #line 1 "..\..\..\..\UserControls\MainMenu.xaml"
            System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

            #line default
            #line hidden
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
        void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
            this._contentLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm searching under PresentationFramework.dll using reflector , i can't seem to locate any of the themes .dlls where are they physically located ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Microsoft.Windows.Themes` is found in the theme-specific PresentationFramework assemblies. You'll want to add a reference to one of the following depending on which one is referenced in your XAML:

- PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
- PresentationFramework.AeroLite.dll
- PresentationFramework.Classic.dll
- PresentationFramework.Luna.dll
- PresentationFramework.Royale.dll

Comment: "What's referenced in your XAML"? I have no references to any such things. Which one should I pick? I'll post my XAML in my question in a second.

Comment: Hmm, I dropped your code in a fresh user control in a fresh WPF project and it doesn't produce that using statement for me. Where exactly in your code does the using statement appear?

Comment: I attached the compiled XAML -> C# code. It shows the `using`. I've tried Clean Solution and then Rebuild Solution without difference.

Comment: I suspect there's something within your `Menu` that contains theme-specific elements. Try just adding a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero.dll and see what happens.

Comment: Works fine after I added `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll`. Hmm.

Comment: @Tower i don't know if i understood you right and if you still needed
it, this is how you reference it via XAML , after adding the Reference to your project of course .  

xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

Comment: I'm searching under PresentationFramework.dll using reflector , 
i can't seem to locate any of the themes .dlls where are they physically located ?

Comment: Thank you for this, in VS2012 Windows.Themes was working then i updated to VS2013 (Worst mistake eva)

Comment: @Tower where can i physically find PresentationFramework.Aero.dll ?

Comment: well i wasn't able to physically locate it , but you can download it from here : 
http://www.dllme.com/dll/download/6959/PresentationFramework.Aero.dll

Comment: I had the same problem and I confirm: Works fine after I added PresentationFramework.Aero.dll